# Palindromic Hypotenuses?

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, palindrome

What is the largest seven-digit palindrome which can be expressed as the sum of two perfect squares?

I tried Java but couldn't get the right answer, and unfortunately [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A087456/list) ends at around 5 digits in.

Comment: Why couldn't you get the right answer with Java?  And how do you know what the right answer is?

Answer (score 3):

$9896989$ is prime and is $\equiv 1\pmod 4$, hence is the sum of two squares.

Comment: Sorry, my former answer was wrong. Do you need the squares?

Comment: Nope, but that was great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It can't end in $99$ since that is $3$ mod $4$.  Therefore it can't start with $99$, so the next-highest prefix is $98$.  Searching numbers of the form $989?989$ quickly yields $9896989$.